# Schematic for 4-band stereo equalizer?

Tags: audio, filter, frequency

I wand to make a simple stereo 4-band EQ for a mid-fi amp I'm building. I draw my knowledge from [this](http://www.geofex.com/article_folders/eqs/paramet.htm) excellent article - however, it only seems to talk about peak/notch bands and not low and high pass filtering in the context of a graphic EQ.

1. Could anyone clue me up on circuits for a low-pass and a high-pass band which would fit well in a design such as [this](http://www.geofex.com/article_folders/eqs/greq.gif)?
2. How can I adapt the schematic to work with 20k pots instead of 100k?
3. What are some good center frequencies for my EQ?

Answer (score 1):

A graphic EQ doesn't usually have LP & HP sections (otherwise it wouldn't be graphic). The schematic in your link is a 7 section EQ with sections from about 60Hz to 15kHz. To maintain these extremes with a four-section EQ, you would need two intermediate sections with frequencies of about 400Hz and 2.4kHz to maintain equal logarithmic spacing. These would need these capacitors :-

400Hz  -> C1=15nF, C2=150nF
2400Hz -> C1=2n7,  C2=27nF

(These are the nearest E24 preferred values and are approximate).

Comment: Why would it not be graphic? I though that the property is defined by it having sliders instead of rotary potentiometers. So having shelving filters isn't a good idea? I though it'd be better if I could cut everything under 60Hz instead of cutting the frequencies around 60Hz but retaining, say, 20Hz (numbers are arbitrary). Care to elaborate?

Comment: Well you could do that at the two extreme frequencies but you would be unlikely to want to boost all frequencies under 60Hz or above 15kHz - ie raising the sliders. The point I was making is that the configuration made by the sliders depicts the frequency response of the equaliser, which will only be true if the sliders are independent of each other (ie with separate passbands). Most GR/EQs I have seen have a separate low-cut filter switch which provides a steep roll-off below say 50 or 75Hz.

Comment: I understand the part about the bands being independent - but why wouldn't I want to boost the extreme bands if their filters were shelving instead of peaking? I mean, Winamp's EQ does it, right :D